# Can I able to add floating filter and checkbox for header group in Ag-Grid to select all the rows

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I need to add floating filter and checkbox in header for Group.

```
 this.autoGroupColumnDef = {
     headerName: " Accession ",
     cellRendererParams: {
         suppressCount: false,
         headerCheckboxSelection: true,
         checkbox: true,
         renderer: "group",
         groupSelectsChildren: true,
         floatingFilter: true,
         filter: true,
         filterParams: {
             filterOptions: ["contains"]
         }
```

Comment: it's possible in floatingFilter ag-grid Ref:https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-floating-filter-component/